# SQL sum of current year commissions is higher than previous year

Tags: sql-server, sum

Trying to compare sum of current year commissions to the previous year but having trouble creating an inner join. If thisYear is higher I will update a growth_incentive field to '.05'  Currently have something like this that gets the data but I feel like its inefficient

```
SELECT   a.emp_no, SUM(a.total_commission) AS ThisYearComm
    ,(select SUM(total_commission) AS LastYearComm
      from  tbl_comm_medmon_employees_stats
      where emp_no = a.emp_no
        and year(getdate())-1 = comm_year) as lastyear
FROM    tbl_comm_medmon_employees_stats a
where   year(getdate()) = a.comm_year
GROUP BY a.emp_no, a.comm_year
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand your table correctly, you don't need a join.  Try using conditional aggregation instead, like this:

```
SELECT   a.emp_no
    , SUM(case when year(getdate()) = a.comm_year then a.total_commission end) AS ThisYearComm
    , SUM(case when year(getdate()) - 1 = a.comm_year then a.total_commission end) AS LastYearComm
FROM    tbl_comm_medmon_employees_stats a
where  a.comm_year in (year(getdate()),  year(getdate()) - 1)
GROUP BY a.emp_no
```

Comment: This works great! Thanks a ton.  I had something really close, but abandoned b/c i couldnt get the join to work, should have thought trying without.

This was my other attempt
 SELECT   thisYear.emp_no
   ,SUM(thisYear.total_commission) AS ThisYearComm
   ,SUM(lastYear.total_commission) AS LastYearComm
 FROM tbl_comm_medmon_employees_stats thisYear
 LEFT JOIN tbl_comm_medmon_employees_stats lastYear
  ON thisYear.comm_year = (lastYear.comm_year - 1)
 GROUP BY thisYear.emp_no, thisYear.comm_year

Comment: You dont need the `WHERE` statement, that is already include it on the `CASE`

Comment: @JuanCarlosOropeza yes you do, if you have employees who were active in prior years, but not the most recent years.  Otherwise, you will get a row for every employee in the table, and a 0 for both aggregations.

Answer (score 0):

You could try to use a conditional `SUM` instead

```
SELECT  a.emp_no, 
        SUM(CASE WHEN year(getdate())-1 = a.comm_year THEN a.total_commission 
                  ELSE 0
             END) [LastYear],
        SUM(CASE WHEN year(getdate())   = a.comm_year THEN a.total_commission 
                  ELSE 0 
             END) [ThisYearComm]
FROM    tbl_comm_medmon_employees_stats a
GROUP BY a.emp_no
```